# java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.TreeSet although I implemented Comparable

Tags: java

I am getting the below error when I cast HashSet to TreeSet. The catch here is I have implemented Comparable and my custom class are sorted as per the compareTo method that I declared. So is there anything I have to consider? Pl can u help?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.TreeSet

Comment: Somewhere in the code, you are doing a wrong cast. The error says it

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

http://beginnersbook.com/2014/08/how-to-convert-a-hashset-to-a-treeset/

This is what I was trying. As you can see the line

```
Set<String> tset = new TreeSet<String>(hset);
```

in the post showing how to cast.

but in my code I was casting as follows so I was getting errors

```
 Set<String> tset = (TreeSet) hset;
```

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` and `HashSet` are "brothers": they both are subclasses of [AbstractSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html). That means that one cannot be cast to another, none of them is a parent of another. Casting specification may be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1).

If your object is also an instance of `Comparable`, you may want to cast it to `Comparable`:

```
// type parameters are not included 
Comparable newComparableObject = (Comparable) yourComparableHashSet;
```